I'm using Formidable function in my Code but why it is not working?
I'm using formidable but it is not working.
Here is my code - I'm getting error on formidable, showing that

Type error: Formidable is not a function

const categoryModel = require('../../models/categoryModel')
const formidable = require("formidable")
const {responseReturn} = require('../../utiles/response')
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2

class categoryController {
    add_category = async(req,res) => {
        
           const form = formidable()
            form.parse(req, async(err, fields, files) => {

                console.log(files)
                console.log(fields)

                /*if(err) {
                   responseReturn(res,404,{error : 'something error'}) 
                }
                else {
                   let {name} = fields
                   let {image} = files
     
                   name = name.trim()
                   const slug = name.split(' ').join('-')

                   cloudinary.config({
                      cloud_name : process.env.cloud_name,
                      api_key : process.env.api_key,
                      api_secret : process.env.api_secret,
                      secure : true
                   })
                try {
                    const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(image.filepath,{folder : 'categorys'})
                    if(result){
                       const category = await categoryModel.create({
                        name,
                        slug,
                        image: result.url
                       })
                       responseReturn(res,201,{category, message : 'CATEGORY add success'})
                    }else{
                        responseReturn(res,404,{error : 'image upload fail'})
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    responseReturn(res,500,{error : 'internal server error'})
                }
                
               }*/
            }
            )
    }

    get_category = async(req,res) => {
        console.log('olj')
    }
}

module.exports = new categoryController() 

I tried by console.log, but it is showing error that formidable is not a function, type error, I'm trying to working with it but no solution
